# Axios Await Stalling Program

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, yeoman-generator

I have an async function in my App.js file (below) of a Yeoman generator PowerPoint task pane plugin where I use the following line:

`let response = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/crop/i');`

In the version of the file in my repository, I isolated that this line is keeping my program from continuing to execute and I'm not sure why it's doing so. If I comment out the line everything runs fine, but trying to use the parsed JSON to replace the "Hello world" string below or even leaving the Axios line in there keeps it from function properly. I'm doing everything right so I was wondering whether there's a very technical js/react architecture convention I'm missing?

[GitHub mirror link to App.js file](https://github.com/wendulem/croppingadd-in/blob/master/src/taskpane/components/App.js)

```js
// App.js
import * as React from "react";
import { Button, ButtonType } from "office-ui-fabric-react";
import Header from "./Header";
import HeroList, { HeroListItem } from "./HeroList";
import Progress from "./Progress";
import { element } from "prop-types";
const axios = require('axios');
/* global Button, console, Header, HeroList, HeroListItem, Office, Progress */

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      listItems: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      listItems: [
        {
          icon: "Ribbon",
          primaryText: "Achieve more with Office integration"
        },
        {
          icon: "Unlock",
          primaryText: "Unlock features and functionality"
        },
        {
          icon: "Design",
          primaryText: "Create and visualize like a pro"
        }
      ]
    });
  }

  click = async () => {

    /*Cropping Code*/  
    /**
     *
     * THIS LINE STALLS MY CODE
     *
     */
    let response = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/crop/i'); //maybe just the route?
    //response.data['text']

    Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(
      "Hello World!",
      {
        coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Text
      },
      result => {
        if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
          console.error(result.error.message);
        }
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { title, isOfficeInitialized } = this.props;

    if (!isOfficeInitialized) {
      return (
        <Progress title={title} logo="assets/logo-filled.png" message="Please sideload your addin to see app body." />
      );
    }

    return (
      <div className="ms-welcome">
        <Header logo="assets/logo-filled.png" title={this.props.title} message="Welcome" />
        <HeroList message="Discover what Office Add-ins can do for you today!" items={this.state.listItems}>
          <p className="ms-font-l">
            Modify the source files, then click <b>Run</b>.
          </p>
          <Button
            className="ms-welcome__action"
            buttonType={ButtonType.hero}
            iconProps={{ iconName: "ChevronRight" }}
            onClick={this.click}
          >
            Run
          </Button>
        </HeroList>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a service running on `127.0.0.1:5000` ? If not, it could be timing out indefinitely waiting for a response that will never arrive. Does [that URL](http://127.0.0.1:5000/crop/i) resolve properly if you visit it manually or via Postman? It's also a good idea to wrap your `await` in a `try...catch` block where you can catch an error if there is one.

Comment: It does resolve with postman and manually. I’ll give a try catch block a shot and see if it works from there.